# ¿Por qué sale en blanco el pdf cuando utilizo customSwitches con rotativa?

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ya me entrega el zip con los pdfs que generé, el que lleva el `customswitches` me borra todo y los demás si tienen información, ¿cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a SOes, revisa el Tour para que veas el funcionamiento de la dinámica del sitio, este sitio es un lugar especial: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> ¡de paso obtienes tu primera medalla! Edita la pregunta por favor, guíate de las siguientes lecturas altamente recomendadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.